# Removing values from Make Variables

Tags: variables, makefile, gnu-make

Using GNU Make I want to remove values from a variable:

```
VAR := x.c y.c z.c
<snip>
VAR += x_x.c y_y.c
```

I now want to remove the "x.c" and "y.c" from the variable. I have tried using subst command but the x_x.c is removed as well.

Are there any ways of doing this?

The final variable should look like:

```
VAR = z.c x_x.c y_y.c
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove item from a Makefile variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402205/remove-item-from-a-makefile-variable)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want the `filter-out` function:

```
VAR := $(filter-out x.c y.c,$(VAR))
```