# Remove item from a Makefile variable?

Tags: variables, makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile, which includes several other makefiles, which in turn all add to a variable like this:

```
VAR := Something SomethingElse
VAR += SomeOtherThing

(...)
```

Now I wish to remove `SomethingElse` from the `VAR` variable. What do I put in place of `(...)` to do this?

I am using GNU Make, and a GNU Make specific solution will be fine.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You could use the [`filter-out` text function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) if you're using GNU Make.

```
OTHERVAR := $(filter-out SomethingElse,$(VAR))
```

Comment: Are both correct in the example I gave? If I use `=` I get a makefile error saying something about VAR eventually referring itself in an infinite recursion. (`VAR = $(filter-out SomethingElse,$(VAR))`)

Comment: That's why I didn't put `VAR =` in my example. If you need to reset `VAR` you probably need simple expansion.

Comment: Just to summarize, it of cause depends on the usage. But in my example the correct answer would be: `VAR := $(filter-out SomethingElse,$(VAR))`  (With `:=` and not `=`). Thanks. :)

Comment: Note: Also can be used on multiple items. Eg: `VAR := $(filter-out A B C,$(VAR))`.

Comment: Note for anyone else coming along. `filter-out` only works on space separated words. If you need to remove something from a string which is not word separated you can use `subst` instead of `filter-out`. I.e: `$(subst -world,,hello-world)` would give the result `hello`.

Answer (score 10):

On top of the correct answer above:

```
VAR = bla1 bla2 bla3 bla4 bla5

TMPVAR := $(VAR)
VAR = $(filter-out bla3, $(TMPVAR))

all:
    @echo "VAR is: $(VAR)"
```

Output:
VAR is: bla1 bla2 bla4 bla5

Note that this breaks all "recursivity" when filter-out is executed, but that might not matter in your case.

Comment: Is this not expected behaviour? Firs you define VAR normally, then you immediately set TMPVAR thus expanding VAR at this point. Then you reset VAR normally to referrer to a filtered out version of TMPVAR. And in the all target your use VAR and thus expand it. I do not see how this breaks recursivity or is in any way problematic behaviour?

Comment: I might have been unclear with what I meant. Imagine having `BLA1 = bla1`, then `VAR = $(BLA1) bla2 bla3 bla4 bla5` instead of the VAR definition above. Executing `BLA1 += bla1111` after the filter-out will have no effect on the value of VAR, since it will have lost its reference to the value of $(BLA1).

Answer (score 0):

As I also have a similar situation, I want to add a new answer. In my case there were also commas into the variable string and, more, I wanted to remove the comma and the last word :

```
VAR = "bla1, bla2"
```

In this case filter out is not working (not even in the previous answers, when there are no quotes)

My solution is to use `subst` :

```
VAR = "bla1, bla2"

TTT = , bla2
TMPVAR := $(VAR)
SUBST = $(subst $(TTT),, $(TMPVAR))
FILT = $(filter-out $(TTT), $(TMPVAR))

subst:
    @echo "subst : $(SUBST)"

filter:
    @echo "filter-out : $(FILT)"
```