# Filter in-place without using a new variable?

Tags: variables, makefile, gnu-make

This is closely related to [Remove item from a Makefile variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7402205).

The answer tells us to use [`filter-out`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html), but it returns in in a new variable. I need it to modify the existing variable.

The issue I am facing is a GNUmakefile that does the following:

```make
SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)
ifeq ($(SRCS),)             # workaround wildcard function bug in GNU Make 3.77
SRCS = $(shell echo *.cpp)
endif

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
```

`SRCS` ends up with a few `*.cpp` files it does not need, like one that is used in a [Borland Developer Studio project](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33691).

How do we filter in-place without using a new variable?

Comment: Does using adding `SRCS := $(filter-out bad.cpp,$(SRCS))` between the `endif` and `OBJS` assignment line work for what you want here?

Comment: Etan's got the right answer.  But, really?  Backward compat for GNU make 3.77... 17 years old now?  Does anyone really still use 3.77 anywhere?

Comment: @MadScientist - This particular library was written in the 1990s. It still supports a lot of older gear, like OpenBSD's GCC 4.2.1. Its got all kinds of goodness baked in :)